# Only one collapsible open at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, shopify

Please note: Started learning Javascript a week ago, excuse my poor knowledge.

I am following the below tutorial:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp

I have not touched the JS, but i have implemented this in a row of 4 that stacks to 2 rows of 2 on mobile.

[image: Issue]

As you can see by the above screenshot, if I open one of the collapsible components, all of them open creating a space underneath all 4 items.

Is there a way to limit this to only having one open at once?

I have tried duplicating the script & css for the first and second row, and naming them collapsible2 etc and it doesn't work.

I've had a look on here and there's nothing specific to this tutorial and only having one open.

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

I would like to only have one collapsible open at once, or limited to one row.

If someone could help with the JS that would be massively appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried? Where do you need help? The logic would just be to close all elements but the clicked one.